# Change Iframe Style When the Src is Set Dynamically

Tags: javascript, iframe, styles

In my site I have this iframe

```
<iframe id='iFrameName1' width='1000' height='500'></iframe>
```

The src tag is dynamically defined with javascript. In addition, I want to dynamically change the style of the iframe (it is in the same domain).

```
<script> function urlChange() {      
var iframe1 = document.getElementById('iFrameName1'); 
iframe1.src = 'mypage.html';
var cssLink = document.createElement("link"); 
cssLink.href = "iframe.css";  
cssLink.rel = "stylesheet";  
cssLink.type = "text/css"; 
iframe1.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cssLink); 
}  
</script>
```

The problem is: as the src is defined dynamically, I think the "iframe1.contentDocument" is not found.

How to solve this problem? I want to define the src and to change the iframe style dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You can handle `onload` event of your iframe like this:

```
iframe1.onload = function(){ 
 ....
}
```

Your code could go like this:

```
function urlChange() {      
    var iframe1 = document.getElementById('iFrameName1'); 
    iframe1.src = 'mypage.html';

    iframe1.onload = function(){
       var cssLink = document.createElement("link") 
       cssLink.href = "iframe.css"; 
       cssLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
       cssLink.type = "text/css"; 
       var y = (iframe1.contentWindow || iframe1.contentDocument);
       if (y.document)y = y.document;
       y.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cssLink);  
    }
}
```

**DEMO**:
http://swift-exploder-php-36-103575.apne1.nitrousbox.com/test/iframe/1.html

The document of `contentWindow` is here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me. I tried, but it did not work. The iframe style did not change.

Comment: @user3676825, I updated my answer. you can use `onload()` for iframe.

Comment: Actually, I'm calling the function on a click of a link: <a href="my_link" onclick="urlChange()">Pages</a>

Comment: Thank you very much. I tested and it worked like a charm. I forgot the onload event. Other question: I noted that the style delays to appear in the iframe. In my case, I will hide some parts of the iframe, so it would be interesting if the style appears instantly. How to do that?